# split and combine a lot of lists by element in R

Tags: r, list

I have a lot (more than 500) R lists from reading some rds objects from a previous step.
Every list contains a different kind of object. Some lists contains data frames, some other parameters, some other models....
Just to illustrate the concept let´s assume whe have:

```
customer_list

customer_list$deutsch
customer_list$nederlands
customer_list$spain
customer_list$france
......

product_list

product_list$deutsch
product_list$nederlands
product_list$spain
product_list$france
```

I want to split/combine all my lists into one object regarding name this way:

```
    deutsch$product
    deutsch$customer


nederlands$customer
nederlands$products
    ....
```

and so on.

A list of lists could be useful too:

```
    huge_list$deutsch
    huge_list$deutsch$customer_list
    huge_list$deutsch$product_list
.......
```

Comment: Please add a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `Map` -

```
#Example
customer_list <- list(deutsch = head(mtcars), nederlands = head(iris))
product_list <- list(deutsch = head(iris), nederlands = head(mtcars))

result <- Map(function(x, y) list(customer_list = x, product_list = y), 
    customer_list[names(product_list)], product_list)
```

In `result` you'll have `result$deutsch$product_list`, `result$deutsch$customer_list` and `result$nederlands$product_list`, `result$nederlands$customer_list`.

Comment: for more than 500 list objects this seems a bit cumbersome. I will try to convert it for processing all in a loop. Thanks